# Update TextBlockData with the new Microsoft Band SDK

Tags: c#, microsoft-band

I want to create a simple app on the Microsoft Band which updates a TextBlock when I click a Button.

I know how to get the trigger event of a button on the band. But I am unable to set a TextBlock if a button is triggered.

```
bandClient.TileManager.TileButtonPressed += (s, args) =>
{
    buttonPressedCount++;
    ((TextBlockData)page3.Values[2]).Text = buttonPressedCount.ToString();
    bandClient.TileManager.SetPagesAsync(args.TileEvent.TileId, page, page2,page3);
};
```

I tried it with changing the page and call the SetPAgeAsync, but this does not work correctly.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: hi there. i'm having issues capturing events triggered from a button. you seem to have it working. do you mind checking out my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35147802/ms-band-sdk-button-pressed-event-handler-not-being-called

Answer (score 1):

OBS- I haven't run this code :)

You seem to be missing an await, and I would also recommend you lift out the event handler out for a few reasons, avoiding GC chucking it away, being able to unsubscribe later to avoid potential memory leaks and to be able to wrap the async call in a try catch without having to clutter up the code. Since the event-handler is returning void the exception wont be propagated, move the event handler out and wrap the async call.

The async call returns a boolean you could use btw

```
// bandClient.TileManager.TileButtonPressed += OnTileButtonPressed;


 private async void OnTileButtonPressed(object s, BandTileEventArgs<IBandTileButtonPressedEvent> e)
{
    try
    {
        buttonPressedCount++;
        ((TextBlockData)page3.Values[2]).Text = buttonPressedCount.ToString();
        await bandClient.TileManager.SetPagesAsync(e.TileEvent.TileId, page, page2, page3);
    }
    catch (BandException ex)
    {
        // Notify
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same thing and finally read every line of their [SDK documentation](http://developer.microsoftband.com/docs/Microsoft%20Band%20SDK.pdf) and found the bad news on page 31.

> Note that the content of the currently displayed page of a tile will not be redrawn on the Band screen even if your
>   app sets new content to that page. The page is redrawn with the new content if it scrolls off the Band screen and
>   then back on, or if the tile is exited and reopened by the user.

I'm going to play around with adding and removing pages in order for my new content to be a new page and see if that will work. Not a solution by any means, but I need to try something.  This really frustrates me that we can't update our content and have it redrawn.